# Communications between tray app and javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I am wondering how browser client side Javascript code is able to communicate with an application that is running on the operating system (same OS that is running browser).  What cross platform technology / protocol would be involved to get this done (please explain with some level of detail)?

Comment: You need to be more concrete how this should look like. I imagine some webservices / REST or Websocket

Comment: So your saying javascript/Ajax post some info to a cloud service, then the tray application picks it up using the same cloud service.  I guess that could work, I was hoping for something more direct between javascript and the OS.

Comment: Would it be possible to store data in the browser local DB, and then the tray application reading that local browser DB?

Comment: In that scenario you would need some API that allows access to any browsers local storage (Chrome, Firefox, IE, ...) from a binary running on your OS. I don't think that something like this is available.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly possible unless the other application is/has a webserver with CORS enabled (assuming the client-side code isn't being served by the same application), and then one would do it in the traditional ways (AJAX and `script` tags primarily)

Comment: I can think of a scenario where you have a native application (exe for example) that waits for input coming in from a web application. As CORS is something imposed by browsers the native application could definitely ignore that.